# How to add a x-scroll on a division of a shiny app?

Tags: html, r, shiny

The following code should add endless number of column and a scroll bar should appear at the bottom. But the scroll bar is not working here. Please help..

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
   actionButton("addCol","Add New Column"),
   div(style="overflow-x: auto;",
            uiOutput("myUI")
   )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  alld <- reactiveValues()
  alld$ui <- list()

  observeEvent(input$addCol,{

    alld$ui[[length(alld$ui)+1]] <- verbatimTextOutput("aaa", placeholder = T)

    output$myUI <- renderUI({
      fluidRow(lapply(alld$ui,function(x){column(4,x)}))
  })})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: The scrollbar shows up correctly or? But since you define columns with a width of 4, you can only include 3 columns within 1 row (as 12 is maximum row width), then it will start showing a "new" row.

Comment: @SeGa I tried with  div(class = "column",x) also.. But did not worked.. New columns are not taking place beyond the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) layout (`fluidPage`, `fluidRow`, `column`), and the whole idea behind this kind of layout is responsivity.

The page is considered 12 width, and elements exceeding that will wrap to new rows. This is the intended behaviour of Bootstrap.

One way of solving your problem is to use [flexbox](https://cssreference.io/flexbox/).

**Solution**: (Disclaimer: Only works on chrome and firefox)

I made two changes to your code:

1. Changed the `column` to `div` with a custom CSS class called `custom-column`.

`column(4,x)` to `div(class = "custom-column", x)})`

2. Added `flex-nowrap` class to `fluidRow`.

`fluidRow(class="flex-nowrap", lapply(alld$ui,function(x){div(class = "custom-column", x)}))`

With these changes the layout works as you intended on **chrome** and **firefox**, but it's not working on IE or the browser within RStudio.

Full code including the CSS classes `flex-nowrap` and `custom-column`:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    tags$head(tags$style("
      .flex-nowrap {
        display: inline-flex;
        -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap !important;
        -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap !important;
        flex-wrap: nowrap !important;
        flex-direction: row;
      }

      .custom-column {
        width: 200px;
        margin: 0px 10px;
      }      
      "
    )),
    actionButton("addCol","Add New Column"),
    div(style="overflow-x: auto;",
        uiOutput("myUI")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  alld <- reactiveValues()
  alld$ui <- list()

  observeEvent(input$addCol,{

    alld$ui[[length(alld$ui)+1]] <- verbatimTextOutput("aaa", placeholder = T)

    output$myUI <- renderUI({
      fluidRow(class="flex-nowrap", lapply(alld$ui,function(x){div(class = "custom-column", x)}))
    })})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Output**:

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks for your help.. But I am getting another consequent problem asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54254903/flex-wrap-zoom-and-sliderinput-are-not-working-together