# flex-wrap, zoom, and sliderInput are not working together

Tags: r, shiny

This is a consequent problem of [another problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54215125/how-to-add-a-x-scroll-on-a-division-of-a-shiny-app). Solution of the linked problem is given. But for a simple modification it gives another problem.

In the solution I have added the 'zoom:0.5;'. Now zoom is working but I am unable to slide the sliderInput properly.

1. Slider in 1st column works fine
2. Slider in 2nd column move from 5 to 10
3. 3rd and on wards do not move

The code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    tags$head(tags$style("
      .flex-nowrap {
        display: inline-flex;
        -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap !important;
        -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap !important;
        flex-wrap: nowrap !important;
        flex-direction: row;
      }

      .custom-column {
        width: 200px;
        margin: 0px 10px;
      }      
      "
    )),
    actionButton("addCol","Add New Column"),
    div(style="zoom:0.5;overflow-x: auto;",
        uiOutput("myUI")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  alld <- reactiveValues()
  alld$ui <- list()

  observeEvent(input$addCol,{

    alld$ui[[length(alld$ui)+1]] <- sliderInput("aaa","",1,10,5)

    output$myUI <- renderUI({
      fluidRow(class="flex-nowrap", lapply(alld$ui,function(x){div(class = "custom-column", x)}))
    })})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Using `zoom` is [not advised](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/zoom/). I think the best idea is to set the `max-width` property for your custom column class, which is by default 300px. i.e.: `max-width: 150px`. Or you can try to play around with [transform](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform/)

Comment: You can use the CSS `.irs-bar,.irs-line,.irs-slider { transform: scaleY(0.5); }`